# C: A newline gets printed automatically although no '\n' is used in the printf command

Tags: c, printf, newline

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
int a,b,c;
printf("Enter the numbers:\n");
scanf("%d %d %d", &a,&b,&c);
printf("%d %d %d",a,b,c);
return 0;

}
```

Although no '\n' has been used, the output is:

```
C:\Users\Public\Prac>gcc prac.c
C:\Users\Public\Prac>a
Enter the numbers:
1 2 3
1 2 3
C:\Users\Public\Prac>
```

I fail to understand why this is happening. Would be very grateful if anyone could help!

Comment: when the same is executed on linux, result is as expected.                             Enter the number:                                                            1 2 3                                                                              1 2 3user@user-pc$

Comment: After typing 3 numbers you pressed Enter key - new line is from it.

Comment: @AlexFarber: My interpretation of this question is that it is not about the newline between user input and program output, but instead about the newline after the end of the program output, and before the "C:\Users\Public\Prac>" prompt. That's a thing that Windows and Linux does differently, so I can understand a question about that. Less so a question about why a newline appears when pressing ENTER.

Answer (score 4):

Windows just adds a newline before the prompt. Linux does not.

(This is a constant annoyance to me. I teach C programming, and my students mostly use Windows. I myself mostly use Linux, and I test run their programming assignments on Linux. Their programs *always* leave the last line mixed up with my prompt.)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: "After the text from the input and output of the previous command, and before the next prompt". Or how would you express it?

Comment: To me (but I'm not an English speaker) it sounds (even in your comment) it's added because of the prompt (printf) but actually it's last user input (btw still in stdin) from scanf. It's not _added_ by Windows, it's not _removed_ and echoed to stdout.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: To me, the "prompt" in this case is the "C:\Users\Public\Prac>", and not anything printed by the program.

Comment: Well then nothing to do with OP's question. _Problem_ is new-line between user input (1 2 3) and program output (1 2 3 but with a new-line before it).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti: I think we interpret the question differently. The OP is (according to my interpretation) _not_ asking about the newline between user input and program output, but instead of the newline after the end of the program output, and before the "C:\Users\Public\Prac>" prompt.